# Key commands for creating temporary tables

Tags: mysql

I am creating temporary tables in stored procedures. Wanted to know what commands to include in procedure to avoid conflicts?

i usually use below syntax

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_shipmentcount
```

and use

drop command at end.

should i add drop command at beginning of procedure also?

Comment: You can also truncate it to make sure it is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Temporary` tables are connection scoped. They only exist until the connection is closed.

As per documentation on [*`Temporary tables`*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html#idm47390082160576)

> *You can use the `TEMPORARY` keyword when creating a table. A `TEMPORARY` table is visible only to the current connection, and is dropped automatically when the connection is closed. This means that two different connections can use the same temporary table name without conflicting with each other or with an existing non-`TEMPORARY` table of the same name...*

If a connection is not closed but shared among users, then you have to `drop` it and re-create. But dropping a database object using a shared connection will result issues.

It would be a better option to use temporary tables with runtime generated names within a stored procedure. This is safe on using shared connection objects too.

**Exampe**:

```
set @temp_table_name := concat( 'temp_table_', ( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 0 ) );

set @sql := concat( 'create temporary table ', @temp_table_name );
set @select_stmt := concat( 'select this', blah, blah );
set @sql := concat( @sql, ' as ' , @select_stmt );

prepare stmt from @sql;
execute stmt;
drop prepare stmt;

-- perform opearations on temp table
--
-- in between here
--
-- and then drop it before leaving

set @drop_temp := concat( 'drop temporary table ', @temp_table_name );
prepare stmt from @drop_temp;
execute stmt;
drop prepare stmt;
```

Comment: what do u mean by shared among users??? Do you mean using PCONNECT for connections??

Comment: Within a connection pool if a connection is shared and not closed until a specific time lapse.

Comment: What chances are there if 2 users get same table name?

Comment: So long as the connection is not shared, dup names on temp tables are accepted. But chances in shared connections are inevitable. You should opt a generic algorithm to generate user specific or `rand()` string reformatted and used with temp table names.

Comment: How do we check if connection is shared or not. Any configuration variable?

Comment: No. That depends on application server side configuration on data sources.

Comment: Also read [*Controlling the Lifecycle of a Connection*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/manage.htm#BABFBFDE).